PowerBI adds duplicate columns to an Azure Data Explorer datetime table when using direct query
we have created a connection from PowerBI to our Azure DataExplorer database and we use the following kusto code as the source query. The connection is also set to direct query mode:
Table
| distinct  10MinBin = todatetime(datetime_add("minute", 10, bin(TimeGenerated, 10min)))
| extend year = datetime_part('year', 10MinBin), month=datetime_part('month', 10MinBin), day = datetime_part('day', 10MinBin), 
hour=datetime_part('hour', 10MinBin), minute = datetime_part('minute', 10MinBin)
| project ['10MinBin'], year, month, day, hour, minute

This simply gives us a table of distinct 10 minute bins and some parts of that datetime object such as year, month, day, hour, minute.
When I check the total count and total distinct count, they are the same which means there are no duplicate values in the final result.
Our issue is when we use direct query to access this table in PowerBI, it seems like PowerBI adds some duplicates to our table and when we try to create relationships between this table and other tables, we get a many-to-many relationship because PowerBI complains that this table has duplicate values (which is not the case). Therefore, we cannot create a one-to-many relationship between this table and our fact table which is causing some issues to us.
Has anyone faced a similar issue before when connecting from PowerBI to ADX? There is a thread  with a similar issue which you can check.
Thanks for the help

you could try casting it to a string format using format_datetime(datetime_add("minute", 10, bin(TimeGenerated, 10min)), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').
